# Create MySQL trigger that subtracts quantity in the order from quantity in stock

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

This is what I have so far and I keep syntax errors.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER quantUpdate
AFTER INSERT ON item 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE item SET quantityInStock = quantityInStock -quantity;      
END $$
```

Comment: 1) you ended the update fommand before the set part 2) you seem to be unable to distinguish between a table and a field in the update.

Answer (score 1):

Got it! I had to figure out when it was appropriate to use `NEW.field`. I didn't realize that I could compare two fields from different tables. Good to know.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER quantUpdate
AFTER INSERT ON orderItem 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE item SET quantityInStock = quantityInStock - NEW.quantity;      
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```